# Why doesn't the video load in this video player web component?

Tags: javascript, web, web-component, lit-element

I have the following code for the web component which should start video streaming of the cam when the user clicks on the button

```
class WebStream extends LitElement { 
constructor(){
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
}
render() {
    return html` 
        <button @click="${this.startStreaming}">start streaming</button>
    `;
}
startStreaming() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true
    }).then(function(mediaStream){
        const shadowRoot = this;
        let shadow = document.createElement("div")
        shadowRoot.appendChild(shadow);
        this.video = document.createElement('video'); 
        shadow.appendChild(this.video);
        this.video.srcObject = mediaStream
        console.log(mediaStream)
        this.video.setAttribute("width", "320");
        this.video.setAttribute("height", "240");
        this.video.play()
    }.bind(this))
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error)
    })                    
}
```

}

with this code it starts streaming, and I can listen the audio but on the browser I cant see anything

Answer (score 1):

In native code its:

But it won't run as SO Snippet, so see the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/btqvynd3/

```html
<web-cam></web-cam>

<script>
  customElements.define("web-cam", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode:'open'}).innerHTML=`<video></video>`;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
          video: { width: 320, height: 240 },
        }).then((mediaStream) =>{
          this.video = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('video');
          this.video.srcObject = mediaStream;
          this.video.play();
          this.onclick = (evt) => {
            this.video.pause();
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
  })
</script>
```

Note: the error in your code is a 'this' reference to **lightDOM**, NOT to the Components shadowRoot

```
 const shadowRoot = this;
 let shadow = document.createElement("div")
 shadowRoot.appendChild(shadow);
```